# Reverse Engineering an Encryption Algorithm

Tags: encryption, decryption

I have a program that has the ability to encrypt files and I want to be able to create a program that can read these files. I believe it uses a Blowfish encryption, but I'm not certain on that. How can I find the type of encryption used and its key?

Using Reflector, I was able to find the following code:

```
public static unsafe string Encrypt(string text)
{
    string str;
    basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > local2;
    sbyte modopt(IsSignUnspecifiedByte)* numPtr = (sbyte modopt(IsSignUnspecifiedByte)*) Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(text);
    std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >.{ctor}(&local2, numPtr);
    try
    {
        basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > local;
        IntPtr hglobal = new IntPtr(numPtr);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hglobal);
        basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >* localPtr = _Encrypt(&local, (basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > modopt(IsConst)* modopt(IsImplicitlyDereferenced)) &local2);
        try
        {
            str = new string(std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >.c_str((basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > modopt(IsConst)* modopt(IsConst) modopt(IsConst)) localPtr));
        }
        fault
        {
            ___CxxCallUnwindDtor(std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >.{dtor}, (void*) &local);
        }
        std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >.{dtor}(&local);
    }
    fault
    {
        ___CxxCallUnwindDtor(std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >.{dtor}, (void*) &local2);
    }
    std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >.{dtor}(&local2);
    return str;
}
```

I notice it also references this, but I don't understand what it does at all...

```
[PreserveSig, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Unmanaged, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Native), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal static unsafe basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >* modreq(IsUdtReturn) modopt(CallConvCdecl) _Encrypt(basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >*, basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > modopt(IsConst)* modopt(IsImplicitlyDereferenced));
```

I'm still new to desktop programming, my only programming experience is mostly with web-based technologies and the absolute basics of C++. I've never gotten into reverse engineering before either. So please be gentle and thorough in your response as I'd really like to learn.

-------------- EDIT

I've finally been able to find the same function call in OllyDBG. However, setting a breakpoint and making it run the code does not cause it to break.

What might I be doing wrong? :/

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                            Comments
00A088D8  /$  02            ldarg.0
00A088D9  |.  7B CC000004   ldfld openFileDialog3
00A088DE  |.  02            ldarg.0
00A088DF  |.  6F D101000A   callvirt ShowDialog
00A088E4  |.  17            ldc.i4.1
00A088E5  |.- 2E 01         beq.s 0A088E8
00A088E7  |.  2A            ret
00A088E8  |>  02            ldarg.0
00A088E9  |.  7B CC000004   ldfld openFileDialog3
00A088EE  |.  6F 8501000A   callvirt get_FileName
00A088F3  |.  28 D201000A   call ReadAllText
00A088F8  |.  0A            stloc.0
00A088F9  |.  06            ldloc.0
00A088FA  |.  6F 9000000A   callvirt Trim
00A088FF  |.  6F 3900000A   callvirt get_Length
00A08904  |.- 2D 01         brtrue.s 0A08907
00A08906  |.  2A            ret
00A08907  |>  06            ldloc.0
00A08908  |.  6F 9000000A   callvirt Trim
00A0890D  |.  72 99340070   ldstr "ENCRYPTED"                  ; UNICODE "ENCRYPTED"
00A08912  |.  6F D301000A   callvirt StartsWith
00A08917  |.- 2C 1F         brfalse.s 0A08938
00A08919  |.  02            ldarg.0
00A0891A  |.  72 AD340070   ldstr "File is already encrypted"  ; UNICODE "File is already encrypted"
00A0891F  |.  28 14000006   call Translate
00A08924  |.  72 E1340070   ldstr "Error"                      ; UNICODE "Error"
00A08929  |.  28 14000006   call Translate
00A0892E  |.  16            ldc.i4.0
00A0892F  |.  1F 10         ldc.i4.s 10
00A08931  |.  28 D401000A   call Show
00A08936  |.  26            pop
00A08937  |.  2A            ret
00A08938  |>  06            ldloc.0
00A08939  |.  28 D501000A   call Encrypt
00A0893E  |.  0A            stloc.0
00A0893F  |.  06            ldloc.0
00A08940  |.  6F 9000000A   callvirt Trim
00A08945  |.  6F 3900000A   callvirt get_Length
00A0894A  |.- 2D 01         brtrue.s 0A0894D
00A0894C  |.  2A            ret
00A0894D  |>  02            ldarg.0
00A0894E  |.  7B CC000004   ldfld openFileDialog3
00A08953  |.  6F 8501000A   callvirt get_FileName
00A08958  |.  02            ldarg.0
00A08959  |.  7B CC000004   ldfld openFileDialog3
00A0895E  |.  6F 8501000A   callvirt get_FileName
00A08963  |.  72 ED340070   ldstr ".bak"                       ; UNICODE ".bak"
00A08968  |.  28 3A00000A   call Concat
00A0896D  |.  17            ldc.i4.1
00A0896E  |.  28 B700000A   call Copy
00A08973  |.  02            ldarg.0
00A08974  |.  7B CC000004   ldfld openFileDialog3
00A08979  |.  6F 8501000A   callvirt get_FileName
00A0897E  |.  06            ldloc.0
00A0897F  |.  28 A200000A   call WriteAllText
00A08984  |.  02            ldarg.0
00A08985  |.  72 F7340070   ldstr "File encrypted"             ; UNICODE "File encrypted"
00A0898A  |.  28 14000006   call Translate
00A0898F  |.  72 15350070   ldstr "Info"                       ; UNICODE "Info"
00A08994  |.  28 14000006   call Translate
00A08999  |.  16            ldc.i4.0
00A0899A  |.  1F 40         ldc.i4.s 40
00A0899C  |.  28 D401000A   call Show
00A089A1  |.  26            pop
00A089A2  \.  2A            ret
```

Comment: I just skipped over your post and I read the part where you said you can't write basic desktop applications. I'd recommend you learn the bare basics of this first. Reverse Engineering a car for example would require some knowledge on mechanical engineering.

Answer (score 1):

```
[PreserveSig, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Unmanaged, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Native), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
```

You see the first part saying unmanaged? .net is a 'managed' environment. As this is referred to the memory, I can tell you C and C++ are not (beware of C++.net as that is managed C++.

Anyway, by the looks of this I'd say it calls the function from an external source (I'd suspect a DLL).

```
internal static unsafe basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >* modreq(IsUdtReturn) modopt(CallConvCdecl) _Encrypt(basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >*, basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > modopt(IsConst)* modopt(IsImplicitlyDereferenced));
```

This says things about the method it is called `Cdecl` the function is called _Encrypt and has a few arguments.

Hope this helped, now you should first learn the basics, especially when you are going to dive into disassembling this native code.

Comment: Stolas, thanks. That helps shed some like on things. I had a hunch that it was in an external library, but wasn't sure. What would be the next step in locating it? I've found the function in OllyDBG but don't know how to break and step through it.

Comment: Try process monitor for example. Have a look on this Stack Exchange as there are some Questions about the basics and how to continue after installing OllyDBG.